# Jquery localstorage NaN error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to gamify my website and reward users for doing things like scrolling down, clicking to the next page etc.

But when the page loads I get sometimes a "NaN" instead of the saved score from the localstorage. To reproduce the error scroll down and refresh some times and you will see it at the blue box.

Comment: `parseInt(localStorage.getItem('score'));` will produce NaN for example when the Item "score" is not existing (return null)

Comment: use browser console to debug what the actual values are

Comment: If you're going to remove all the code from the question, you might as well delete it completely. This won't benefit anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Doing **parseInt** on a **undefined** or **null** gives you NaN (not a number)